# Php permission denied on connection to /tmp/redis.socket on cpanel

Tags: centos, php, cpanel, redis

I have installed redis on my Cpanel Centos 6.9 VPS and successfully connected to it via tcp. I wanted to share redis.socket connection instead of tcp with several users on my vps but failing to do so as php throws an error with permission denied.

I have already tried to set permission to /tmp/redis.socket 755, even to 777, 
though I understand that there is no point in that as it only adds write permission.

I have tried to run service as redis user and relocate socket location to /home/redis/redis.socket.

But no matter what I try it throws permission denied error.

I also understand that giving access to socket of single instance to multiple users may cause problems, but I do manage most of the sites on my vps, so it should not be an issue.

Could you please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect via socket by running redis with `redis:redis` user and changing location of socket file in config to `/var/lib/redis/redis.sock` and setting permissions to 777, as well as I had to set `dir` settings to folder where redis user had an access to, and I could not write into `/var/log/redis.log` so had to move redis log to its home directory.